# How do I set two teminals side-by-side by one command or setting automatically?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to set two-column layout of terminals by default, is it possible?

[image: Two-column layout with terminals]

The problem is the left one is created by `Npm` built-in extension and I cannot freely type anything in this terminal. This terminal instance is created from `Npm scripts view` in File Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

For everything that is not natively supported in VSCode, there is an extension.

Look for `split terminal` in the extensions and you will find the `Split Terminal on Startup` extension.
It will do exactly what you are looking for.

[image]